# How to make poster from many PDF pages?

Tags: pdf

I have a PDF document with standard 8.5 x 11 pages. (It's actually a printout of my code.) I would like to make a power out of this so I can print it out on some big sheet of paper.

**Does anyone know of a tool to do this?** There are plenty of tools to do the opposite—take a poster and print it on several smaller pieces of paper that can be taped together.

Comment: Isn't this a matter handled by your printer driver?

Comment: @Refineo I don't know. I'm not that familiar with what printer drivers do vs what they just accept as input.

Comment: Maybe you could check if your printer driver has in the properties window, advanced properties, "poster mode" or "scaling" or "fit to pages" printing settings. Search for anything related to "scaling" or "zooming".